# gatling 3.2: Get json from rest endpoint, change it and return it

Tags: gatling

I am new to gatling and new to scala. I am looking to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011052/gatling-get-rest-resource-change-json-leaf-post-back) in gatling 3.2

I need to save json from a rest endpoint, insert data into the json that I have saved into a session then return the json back.

The json looks like this:

```
{
"authnId": "abc123",
"authnData": [
    {
        "type": "Username",
        "input": [
            {
                "name": "token1",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "Password",
        "input": [
            {
                "name": "token2",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    }
]}
```

I have a feeder:

```
val userFeeder: Iterator[Map[String, String]] = Iterator.continually(Map(
"""username""" -> (simConfig.userPrefix + random.nextInt(simConfig.userPoolSize).toString),
"""password""" -> simConfig.userPassword)
)
```

And I need to return this (assuming it's best to insert gatling placeholders here, I'm not sure it is):

```
{
"authnId": "abc123",
"authnData": [
    {
        "type": "Username",
        "input": [
            {
                "name": "token1",
                "value": "${username}"
            }
        ],
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "Password",
        "input": [
            {
                "name": "token2",
                "value": "${password}"
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

}

Here is part of my simulation:

```
        .exec(
            http("get json")
            .post(simConfig.authnUrl)
            .check(status.is(200))
            .check(jsonPath("$.authnId").find.saveAs("authnId"))
            .check(jsonPath("$").find.saveAs("jsonbody")))
            .exitHereIfFailed
        .exec(session => {
            //modify jsonbody here
        })
        .feed(userFeeder)
        .exec(http("submit credentials")
            .post(config.authnUrl)
            .disableUrlEncoding
            .asJson
            .body(StringBody("$jsonbody")
            )
            .check(status.is(200))
            .check(jsonPath("$.authnId").find.saveAs("ssoToken"))
        ).exitHereIfFailed
```

What's the best way to do this in gatling 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand you, try use [ElFileBody](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#request-body)

At first create json where define variable with gatling el expression `"value": "${password}"`

And then:

```
.post(...)
.body(ElFileBody("request.json")).asJson
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what I want to do. I need to inject a session variable into json that originally came from a previous response, then post that json back. That response is dynamic in nature, I can't supply it as a static string or file.

Comment: ...that said, I see now that using ElFileBody is partially what I need to do, thanks! Do you know what the best way is to modify the json string to include ${username} and ${password} ?

Comment: @simon Use your feed. Or you can get and save variable from request `.check(jsonPath("$.username").saveAs("username"))`

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to transform JSON based on Session information. That's something you'll have to code yourself (Jackson, Circe or whatever Scala lenses library you'd like as long as performance matches your needs).

```scala
.exec(
  http("get json")
    .post(simConfig.authnUrl)
    .check(bodyString.saveAs("jsonbody"))
)
.feed(userFeeder)
.exec(
  http("submit credentials")
    .post(config.authnUrl)
    .asJson
    .body(
      StringBody { session =>
        val username = session("username").as[String]
        val password = session("password").as[String]
        val jsonbody = session("jsonbody").as[String]
        jsonbody // return here the result of your transformation
      }
    )
  )
```